# Victory Charts: Using labels with bar charts

Tags: reactjs, svg, victory-charts

I am leveraging VictoryCharts to add charts to my React app. I am trying to accomplish something like:

[image: like This]

I combed through the docs and was not able to find a way to add Labels to a single bar chart.

**Things I have tried**

1. Nesting `<VictoryLabel> and``under```` --> The axes show up and the docs recommend using [VictoryGroup](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/faq/#how-do-i-turn-off-the-axes-on-victorychart)
2. Nesting `<VictoryLabel> and``under```` --> VictoryGroup [does not support](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-group) VictoryLabel
3. Tried making a standalone `<VictoryBar>` & `<VictoryLabel>` and embedding it into `<svg>` --> Cannot see the chart contents on the page

This is the snippet I have right now:

```js
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import React from 'react';
import { VictoryAxis, VictoryBar, VictoryChart, VictoryContainer, VictoryLabel, VictoryTheme } from 'victory';

const SampleChart = ({ stat=25, title = 'Sample' }) => (
  <Box ml={5}>
    <svg height={60} width={200}>
      <VictoryLabel text={title.toLocaleUpperCase()} textAnchor='start' verticalAnchor='end' />
      <VictoryBar
        barWidth={10}
        data={[{ y: [stat], x: [1] }]}
        domain={{ y: [0, 100], x: [0, 1] }}
        horizontal
        labels={d => d.y}
        labelComponent={
          <VictoryLabel verticalAnchor='end' textAnchor='start' />
        }
        standalone
        style={{ parent: { height: 'inherit' } }}
        theme={VictoryTheme.material}
      />
    </svg>
  </Box>
);
ReactDOM.render(<SampleChart />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an axis to this effect like so:

```
const CHART_WIDTH = 800;
const val = 28
function BarChart() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: CHART_WIDTH }}>
      <VictoryChart height={200} width={CHART_WIDTH}>
        <VictoryAxis 
          dependentAxis
          tickValues={[0,100]}
          offsetY={190}
          tickFormat={t => t===0 ? 'average age' : val}
          style={{axis: { stroke: 'none'}}}
        />
        <VictoryBar
          barWidth={10}
          data={[{ y: [45], x: [1] }]}
          domain={{ y: [0, 100], x: [0, 1] }}
          horizontal
        />
      </VictoryChart>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RmaxOd?editors=0110#0

Not exactly what you wanted, but it gets the job done, and you can format the tick labels or provide custom components to make it look like your desired result.